# Why does pressing CTRL+C or CTRL+X capitalize the letter instead of exit or their normal EXIT in Raspbian Jessie Lite

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, command-line-interface, debian-jessie

I am using the most recent version of *Raspbian Jessie*.

I'm in the terminal but the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit a *PING* command for example doesn't work.

Is it because I changed my locale to *en_US.UTF-8*? Just a guess.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> doesn't work

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I've never known *ping* on *GNU/Linux* distros to respond to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Maybe you are thinking of one of the following typical signal generating *CTRL* inputs:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = SIGINT (terminates ping and prints final statistics)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
  = SIGSTP (stops the ping and allows it to be resumed)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> = SIGQUIT (this one makes ping print out the running statistics)

If you really think something is off, you could check out your keyboard configuration. The config is in `/etc/default/keyboard`.